# Auto Copy and Paste - Ajax/JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I trying to make a cool kind of auto **IMDB ID grabber** that auto grabs the ID while you type the TV Show name, So far all I have gotten was it to check fi the field is empty if its not empty it would show a button you press that brings you to a page with the ID which you manually copy and paste into a field.

Is it possible to make it so it automatically grabs whatever you type in the field, in real time, put it at the end of a link for example: `http://example.com?show=<UserEnteredShow>` which it automatically goes to in the background and copies all browser see-able text and then puts it into another field.

I know this is pretty much overboard but I really want to see this happen. I have no idea where to start for this.

Comment: Don't use GET parameters if you don't want to refresh the page. Instead, [use hashtags at the end](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier). I would write an answer, but your question isn't really clear about what exactly you want.

Comment: sounds like an autocomplete/typeahead field and there are lots of resources available to do this with

Comment: @NobleMushtak im trying to basically make a field that when you type in it, it will add whatever you typed to the end of a certain url that will open automatically and copy what is on the page and then paste it into a different input field

Comment: Ah...I don't think that shouldn't be too hard. I'll whip up a code snippet to show you how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just get the value of the PHP file using AJAX. If you're really new to AJAX, I recommend using [$.ajax()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) which requires [jQuery](https://jquery.com/).

Whenever the user types something into the first `<input>`, we just send an AJAX request to the server and put the response in the second input.

I don't think Stack Overflow allows for AJAX in code snippets, so put the following code snippet in an HTML file and test it on your Web site:

```js
//Our <input> elements
var toLink = document.getElementById("put-at-end-of-link");
var fromAjax = document.getElementById("copy-from-ajax-request");

//When the value of toLink changes, update fromAjax:
toLink.addEventListener("input", function () {
    //Send an AJAX request to /id.php:
    $.ajax({
        url: "/id.php",
        //This is a GET request:
        type: "GET",
        //We do not want to cause the user lag while we're sending this request, so set async to true:
        async: true,
        data: {name: toLink.value},
        success: function(response) {
            //Once we're done with the response, put it into fromAjax:
            fromAjax.value = response;
        }
    });
});
```

```css
/* Make the input takes up the full screen width and give them some vertical space: */
input {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 1em 0;
}
```

```html
<!--Remember to include the jQuery!-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--The input elements:-->
<input type="text" id="put-at-end-of-link" placeholder="This is where the user enters the value to be sent to /id.php."/>
<input type="text" id="copy-from-ajax-request" placeholder="This is where we output the response from /id.php."/>
```

Comment: I dont understand this from and to link things, Like have you got skype? I can show you what I mean from it

Comment: Ok basically I need to get whatever the user types, put it at the end of: id.php?name=<Put Right Here> then get it to open that page in the background and copy the text that shows up (All that shows up is the id) then paste that in a seperate input field. I need all this to happen withouth reloading the page

Comment: No, I do not have Skype and I'd rather keep this conversation on StackOverflow. Also, the `toLink` and `fromLink` elements are just the elements from HTML. I just get them based off their IDs using `document.getElementById()`.

Comment: You can't do that without reloading the page because it seems like you want to redirect the user to another page by passing GET parameters to PHP. Sending GET parameters always requires redirecting the user to another Web page.

Comment: Oh how would I make it go to a page then and do similar function to this: http://crime.pw/torrents/id.php?name=South%20Park (Click it and change the South Park to whatever tv show) You see it grabs the ID using SimpleHTMLDom how would I be able to do the ?name=<UserTyped> thing withouth reloading the page?

If you go: http://crime.pw/torrents/ you can see the request tv show bit which is the best what I can do right now, If you follow the steps you can see what I want it to do.

Comment: Oh...So you just want to get the info from the page and not actually redirect the user there? That makes a lot more sense. Just use AJAX. If you're new to AJAX, I recommend using [`jQuery.ajax()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Comment: Im so new to it dude xD If you mind can you give me another snippet to base from?

Comment: OK, I edited the above answer. Is this more like how you want it to work?

Comment: It is exactly what im looking for and it works fine but it seems to not work if it has a space in the input field where it adds to the link. Edit: Seems to work kind of properly and not like when I search 'SouthPark' it works fine if i search 'South Park' nothing happens and then when I do 'FamilyGuy' it works and also works when I do 'Family Guy' very odd

Comment: What exactly is the error if there is a space? Does it come out as `%20` or is there some other error?

Comment: I think it searches as %20 yes because when I search Family Guy with space it grab Family Guy: 200 Episodes Later which is found from IMDBwhen you search Family%20Guy on the site directly

Comment: OK, I think I fixed it! In the `data: { name: encodeURIComponent(toLink.value) }`, try getting rid of `encodeURIComponent()` because it looks like jQuery does that for us. Just make it `data: {name: toLink.value}`.

Comment: Awesome that fixed it but I have one more thing, It seems to like search and put into the input field when u click off of the input tag is there any way for it to be almost realtime?

Comment: OK, I think I've implemented it more like how you wanted in my answer above!

Comment: Hmm when its empty it adds some html stuff like doctype etc other then that it seems all good to go :D

Comment: If you want to make sure it doesn't send a request if it's empty, just change the `if` loop in `updateFromAjax()` to `if (toLink.value !== "" && prevLinkToValue !== toLink.value) { [...] }`. Also, I need to leave now, but happy that I could help you!

Comment: Just tested and found out that when you click the input and click on the autocomplete things preset in chrome e.t.c it wont search for the IMDB ID.

Comment: OK, I've changed to the `input` event in the above code snippet which should hopefully listen for Chrome autocomplete.